# Teradata stored procedure with python

Tags: python-3.x, teradata

I'm trying to call a Teradata Stored procedure in python. But it is giving the following error.

```
    cursor = session.cursor()
    cursor.callproc("usr.RESULTSET", (teradata.InOutParam("today"),
                                     teradata.OutParam("p2")))
    output = cursor.fetchone()
    print(output)
```

Error

```
raise DatabaseError(i[2], u"[{}] {}".format(i[0], msg), i[0])
teradata.api.DatabaseError: (6, '[HY000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] (6) Internal Error (Exception).')
INFO:teradata.udaexec: UdaExec exiting. (2019-05-17 10:02:13,350; udaexec.py:68)
```

Comment: Internal exception error... that's 100% not helpful of Teradata. Are you able to call this proc directly in a sql client without it tossing an error? Are you able to submit non-procedure SQL through your python session without the ODBC driver freaking out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to execute the query via bteq file, and now it's giving me the correct result set. Not sure why my previous method failed. bteq file contains the stored procedure and it's parameters.

ex: stored_procedure.bteq

CALL dbname.UsrFail(arg1,arg2)

```
 rows = []
 with td.TeraSession(td_sys_name, td_cred) as session:
    results = session.execute(file="/tperf/stored_procedure.bteq")
    for result in results.fetchall():
        rows.append(result.values)
```